# Laravel force SSL gives 'This webpage has a redirect loop'

Tags: php, ssl, heroku, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.1, and want to force SSL site wide. My app is deployed on Heroku.
Added this to either `App::before` or as a filter:

```
if( ! Request::secure())
{
    return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
}
```

But that gives me 'This webpage has a redirect loop' message.
If I access some page by typing in `https://` by hand, it serves that page correctly; but any link or form action is pointed to `http://`, which I don't want.

Also, I tried to add `https` parameter to some route, e.g.:

```
Route::get('about', ['https', function()
{
    // do something
}]);
```

but this returns 404 :(

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to enforce this on .htaccess level without having to boot the entire framework?

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

Comment: I've tried with similar `.htaccess` redirect, and it generally works fine, except when it redirects POST request - it drops the POST data and opens a route as GET

Comment: How would a user be able to POST to a plain HTTP URL in the first place? If the form is on a HTTPS page (which it should be as your .htaccess forbids plain HTTP), how can a form be sent to a HTTP page?

Comment: @KevinOpdenKamp That wouldn't work; `SERVER_PORT` is always something "random", depending on what port the dyno needs to bind to. Also, SSL is terminated by load balancers. Read from `X-Forwarded-Proto` ("http" or "https") instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue and finally found the solution by using :

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( (Request::header('x-forwarded-proto') <> 'https') && !App::environment('local',     'staging')) {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
    }
});
```

It was due to Heroku passing this information in a different variable than the one used by default by Laravel.

And if you are interested in getting the right environment detection, this is what I used with Laravel and Heroku :

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {
    if (getenv('LARAVEL_ENV')) {
        return getenv('LARAVEL_ENV');
    } else {
        return 'local'; // Default
    }
});
```

You will need to set a "LARAVEL_ENV" environment variable in your different servers with local, staging or production.

With the two, only HTTPS traffic is forced on the production environment.

Comment: This is correct. HTTPS traffic on Heroku is terminated by the load balancers, so requests to dyno backends are always plain HTTP. The X-Forwarded-Proto HTTP header contains "http" or "https" to indicate the protocol of the original client request.