# Laravel HTTPS on Heroku

Tags: laravel, heroku, https

Not sure if anyone else is having a similar issue and gave up, but here goes:

I'm hosting an app on heroku and am using CloudFlare's free SSL to serve all traffic over HTTPS.

Here's the following from the top of my `app/filters.php` file from another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25095936/3008693):

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  if ((Request::header('x-forwarded-proto') <> 'https') && !App::environment('local'))
  {
    return Redirect::secure(Request::getRequestUri());
  }
});
```

For some reason, this breaks all the forms as none of them seem to POST to where they should - they just redirect back to the page containing the original form.

Just in case, here's a part of my `app/routes.php` which is affected:

```
Route::get('login', [
  'as'   => 'login',
  'uses' => 'SessionController@create'
]);

Route::post('login', [
  'as'   => 'login',
  'uses' => 'SessionController@store'
]);
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The connection between your user and CloudFlare is encrypted, but the connection between CloudFlare and your server is not.

As per this article:
https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl

You will need to choose from either Full SSL (requiring only a self signed certificate) or Full SSL (Strict) (requiring a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority).

Comment: Ah I see, I'm currently using Full SSL though and no dice!

Comment: You need to install an SSL certificate on your Heroku environment then. Their support service might be able to advise?

Comment: Ok, will take a look. Thanks for the heads up.